# Software and tutorial for FEM

Tags: finite-element

i'm looking for some advice for finite element analisys. i'm a biomedical engineering student with few knowledge about the FEM.

Tools like Comsol and Ansys are very powerfull but also complex and i feel more industry oriented because of all the premade settings and configuration to learn.

I'd prefer a more basic tool that can get me in finite element analisys more slowly so i can better understand what i'm doing.
So my question is:

is there a code based simple tool or library for FEM and some tutorials to follow that teach me both the math of the method and pratical use of that? 417

Comment: There are several books on FEM with MATLAB which provide you with the code as well. You can follow one of them.
Also, I suggest the textbook Introduction to FEM by J. N. Reddy.

Comment: I'd suggest writing a simple 1D FEM code to understand FEM. The first chapter in Hughes' FEM book provides a nice introduction. After you gain understanding of the basics, you should probably use Commercial/Open Source FEM codes such as deal.II or FEniCS.

Comment: Have you tried the FENICS book and library? It is a nice python library that probably has both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am biased, because I'm one of the authors, but would suggest looking at the [deal.II library](https://www.dealii.org). It has an [extensive tutorial](https://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/Tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3):

Personally I learned most what I know about finite elements from [FreeFEM](https://freefem.org).  It's a complete free package embodying many mathematician-decades of savoir faire.  In particular its domain specific language for describing weak formulations of partial differential equations and boundary value problems is ideal for beginners and facilitates experimentation.